# Installing Xcode 4.3 on El Capitan 10.11

Tags: macos, xcode

How can I install Xcode 4.3 on Mac OS X 10.11 El Capitan ?

Thanks

Comment: Are you looking for a place to download it from, or do you try to install it and run into issues, or did you install it already and now have issues using it?

Comment: when I install an error message occurred  You can't use this version of the application "Xcode" with this version of O.S X

Comment: I think your error message is telling you it can't be done so that's your answer.

Comment: In OS X,we can't install older version of application such as xcode 4.x on mac os x 10.11?

Answer (score 1):

You can download older versions of Xcode from the [Apple developer site](https://developer.apple.com/download/more/).

You will need to register for a free Apple Developer account, if you haven't done so already.